# Within an AnimateKeyFrames block, the wrong keyframe always executes first

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation

I've been working on this simple coin toss iOS app in Swift. I have an animateKeyFrames block to animate the motion of the coin.

The first keyframe causes the coin to go up, the second one assigns the image of a coin depending on the result of a random calculation and the third one brings the coin down.

However, for some reason, the image of the coin always changes first before even going up. It's like the second keyframe is executed first, and I have tried all permutations to no avail. I believe I've even entered the withRelativeStartTime parameter correctly.

What could be happening here?

```
 let animationDuration = 1.5

    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: animationDuration, delay: 0.0, options: [.calculationModeLinear], animations: {

        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0.45, animations: {
            self.imageView.center.y = self.imageView.center.y - 200
            self.imageView.alpha = 0.0
        })

        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 3/7, relativeDuration: 0.1, animations: {
            self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: tossRes)
        })

        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 4/7, relativeDuration: 0.45, animations: {
            self.imageView.center.y = self.imageView.center.y + 200
            self.imageView.alpha = 1.0
        })
    })
```

Comment: Hint: `let secondFrameStartTime = 3/7; print("\(type(of: secondFrameStartTime)) -- \(secondFrameStartTime)")` (And the same applies to the third frame's time.)

Comment: @JoshCaswell Thanks for your comment and the edit! I'm not quite sure if I understand your hint correctly. Are you saying that I need to have a fixed value for the start time of the second frame?

Comment: What is the value of `3/7`?

Comment: @JoshCaswell 0.42. The value for withRelativeStartTime should be between 0 and 1, so I wanted to give equal time for the coin being tossed up and coming down. I'm still unable to figure this out, sorry!

Comment: When you divide integers, you get an integer. Your code is assigning all three frames to start at 0.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Thanks for the response, but changing those integer divisions with a `Double` value did not help. The function still executes first